# What do I need to know about proprietary fonts?

Tags: fonts, licenses

I'm a contract web developer, and I'm working for someone who has a view to create his own web development consultancy. For the project we're currently working on - the graphic designer has provided a design that uses a proprietary font ([Helvetica Neue](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/)).

From that particular site - it looks like you pay for a bundle of page views - 2,500,000 being ~$2500.

The main questions I have are, from the perspective of a person or an organisation that is going to create several websites for different clients:

- What do I need to know about contractual/legal requirements about purchasing proprietary fonts (and other proprietary assets for that matter).
- What are the typically sensible strategies for managing proprietary resources?

Things I'm thinking about are:

- Just include the costs of proprietary content when estimating a job. (In which case - what ballpark figures should be used?)
- Require that the graphic designer includes the font as part of their deliverable? (Is that even possible?)
- Purchase a set of fonts that can be used across all projects, and require that the graphic designer uses them.

Comment: Personally I think that downloading fonts is a huge waste of bandwidth and makes websites slower.  Custom fonts are also slower to read because users are not accustomed to them.  Why use a custom font when the defaults look good enough and are easier to read?  See https://uxplanet.org/10-tips-on-typography-in-web-design-13a378f4aa0d